# Theming Angular Material with custom colours

Tags: angular, angular-material

I want to change the whole theme for my angular 8 app

I have the following in a scss file:

```
@import '~@angular/material/theming';
// Plus imports for other components in your app.

// Include the common styles for Angular Material. We include this here so that you only
// have to load a single css file for Angular Material in your app.
// Be sure that you only ever include this mixin once!
@include mat-core();

// Define the palettes for your theme using the Material Design palettes available in palette.scss
// (imported above). For each palette, you can optionally specify a default, lighter, and darker
// hue. Available color palettes: https://material.io/design/color/
$sp-app-primary: mat-palette($mat-grey,900);
$sp-app-accent:  mat-palette($mat-pink, A200, A100, A400);

// The warn palette is optional (defaults to red).
$sp-app-warn:    mat-palette($mat-red);

// Create the theme object (a Sass map containing all of the palettes).
$sp-app-theme: mat-light-theme($sp-app-primary, $sp-app-accent, $sp-app-warn);


// Include theme styles for core and each component used in your app.
// Alternatively, you can import and @include the theme mixins for each component
// that you are using.
@include angular-material-theme($sp-app-theme);
```

So now my mat-toolbar has a black background so the custom theme is working.

Also I can't for the life of me change the default font colours. I want the text to be orange on a black background but no matter what I do (I have gone through loads of stack overflow posts) the text is always white...

I selected the indigo theme when setting up material. is this causing my issue? Should I have selected custom?

I can't even seem to override the mat-toolbar font colour with standard css classes as they are overridden by the default styles.

It is driving me mad. The angular documentation does not seem to be entirely clear to me.

Comment: Did you check https://material.angular.io/guide/theming-your-components ?

Comment: Yes, but that seems to be for a custom component not for the whole default colour scheme. Also it is not exactly clear on how I change the font colour... (I am not that hot on Scss yet).

Answer (score 0):

Did you try -> https://materialtheme.arcsine.dev ?

It helped me to apply my own custom theme and you can easily customising it for your needs.